# Check value in array returned by mysql_fetch_row in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Hello i am new at php.

```
$res=mysql_query('SELECT `order` FROM `competitions`');
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($res);

    if($row[order] == "1")
            {
            $res=mysql_query('SELECT `name`, `persp`, `teamp` FROM      `competitions_rank` WHERE `comp_id` = '.$_PARAMS[0].' ORDER BY `persp` DESC');
            }
    else
            {
            $res=mysql_query('SELECT `name`, `persp`, `teamp` FROM `competitions_rank` WHERE `comp_id` = '.$_PARAMS[0].' ORDER BY `teamp` DESC');
            }
```

In the database the possible values of the field is null, 1 or 2 .The code always enter in else statement. What i do wrong ? How i should check value in array returned by mysql_fetch_row ?

Answer (score 1):

this  [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) function,
Returns a **numerical array** that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

so in your example you need to check it like :

```
if ($row[0] == "1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions. They're (unofficially) deprecated and not recommended for further use. Second, use `$row["order"]` and not `$row[order]` as there is no such thing as `order` in PHP.

Also, `mysql_fetch_row` returns the row as a **numeric** array, and not associative. if you insist on using `mysql_`, use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

In addition to that, that entire statement should be inside a while loop because there could be more then one line that you are missing. If you want to make sure you only have 1 line, add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your SQL query.

Comment: This isnt working either. What is the alternative of mysql* functions ?

Comment: @Grigori Rangelov Like I said, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` consider rewriting your database coding style to `PDO` or at least to `mysqli`. It would help you with later projects as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in `mysql_fetch_row()`... 
`mysql_fetch_row` — Get a result row as an enumerated array.

USE

```
mysql_fetch_array()
```

then

```
use $row['order']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking but could you update your sql query to

```
$res=mysql_query('SELECT `order` FROM `competitions ORDER BY order`');
```

Failing that you need to change

```
if($row[ 'order' ] == "1")
```